# show $P_n(F)$ is generated by $\{1,x,...,x^n\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

i'm unsure about the quality of this proof. i'm trying to generalize the approach that i use with a given set of polynomials to show that it generates another polynomial or all polynomials of a certain degree. my attempt begins on the next line.

let $a_i \in F, i=0,...,n$

let $f$ be an nth degree polynomial, so $f \in P_n(F)$ and $f=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx_n$

let $b_j \in F, j=0,...,n$, and let $b_j$ be the coefficients of the linear combination of all elements in $\{1,x,...,x^n\}$, i.e.,

$b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...+b_nx^n$

combining the generic polynomial with the generating one as an identity gives:

$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx_n=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...+b_nx^n$

the above result implies $a_i=b_j, (i,j=0,...,n)$

therefore $P_n(F)$ is generated by $\{1,x,...,x^n\}$.

Comment: Isn't $P_n(\mathbb F)$ $\textit {defined}$ to be the linear span of $1, x, \cdots, x^n$ over $\mathbb F$?  If not...how are you defining it?

Comment: i was kind of thinking this as i was writing my proof. but i wrote my proof under the assumption that i can't just take this as a given.

Comment: Well, as I say, you need some definition to start from.  I'd call what I wrote a definition, but your reference may use something else.